forgotten password on wsl vs code
I forgot the password when installing ubuntu on vs code on my pc, and obviously as soon as I want a command with sudo it asks me for the password, do you know of a solution?

I'm not sure what "ubuntu on vs code" means exactly, but you may find one of the answers here helpful: Reset the password in Ubuntu / Linux Bash in Windows

This question is similar to: Reset the password in Ubuntu / Linux Bash in Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
